# How to back up Microsoft Outlook for Mac when export is greyed out

Tags: macos, ms-office

I am trying to back up / export all my emails before I leave my current job. Outlook for Mac shows my export as greyed out. Personal Mac that isn't managed by the company.

Is there a way around this or another way to get a full backup of my email?

Comment: Hmmmmm, on Windows you could just drag the mailboxes out to the desktop, if I recall correctly. What happens if you try that on the Mac: Select all mailboxes that you want and drag them, all at once, to the desktop.

Comment: Is it a managed Mac? If so, it would be a sensible precaution to prevent you removing company data from the premises.

Comment: No this is my personal Mac

Comment: You should be able to create local folders.  Copy your mail messages there.

Answer (score 1):

I setup my email in Apple Mail, then took it offline - I am also able to backup my email using Apple Mail.

Answer (score 1):

Since Microsoft launched the new Outlook for Mac, they have disabled the option to Import / Export .olm and .pst files. They are working on this functionality and will bring it soon to Mac Outlook.

However, if you feel the need to export or backup your data from Mac Outlook, you can either revert your client to Legacy Outlook and then use the Export functionality.

If you don't want to perform this transition to Legacy Outlook, then you can simply use some third-party tool to export or backup your data in PST or any other file format.

You can visit the link to know about the Export process in detail: https://www.emaildoctor.org/blog/export-option-greyed-out-in-outlook-mac-solved/

Comment: Could you edit the answer to how this is fixed instead of just pasting the link?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If the "Export" option is greyed out in Microsoft Outlook for Mac, there are a few other options to try to backup your emails.

1.Create a local backup file: In Outlook for Mac, you can create a local backup file (.olm) that contains all of your emails, contacts, and calendar events. Go to File > Export, choose "Outlook for Mac Data File (.olm)", select the items you want to back up, and follow the prompts to save the backup file to your computer.

2.Use a third-party backup tool: Popular backup tools include Time Machine, Carbon Copy Cloner, and SuperDuper.

3. Copy and paste emails to a local folder: If you only need to backup a few specific emails, select the emails, right-click and choose "Copy", navigate to a local folder and right-click to choose "Paste".

If your email account is hosted on a server, your emails will still be available after you leave your job. However, if you want a local backup, try one of the options above.

Comment: Wouldn't step one be impossible if the export menu is disabled / grayed out? Can you edit this to explain how the problem in the question is addressed?